# Limiting the width and height of a div in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

In the HTML below I'm facing two problems:

1. The random string generated does not fit within the 15% width of the td. I'm not sure how I can have a div be the maximum width of its parent td (in this cas 15% of the width of the screen and a `min-width` of `200px`)
2. I'm not sure what % height to give `#row2` because while I want the whole table to be 100% height / width (and `#row1` to be a little bigger than `#row2` - eg 60 / 40), but I want `#row2` to be fixed at a `height` of `20px`.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function randomString(string_length) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomstring;
  }
  function FillData(){
    document.getElementById("query_div").innerHTML = randomString(1000);
    document.getElementById("box1_div").innerHTML = randomString(1000);
  }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  #global_table{
    /*max-height: 300;
    max-width: 500;
    table-layout:fixed;*/
    min-height:500px;
    /*height:100%;*/
    width:100%;
    max-height:1500px;
  }
  #col1{
    min-width:200px;
    width:15%;
  }
  #col2{
    min-width:200px;
    width:20%;
  }
  #col3{
    min-width:200px;
    width:25%;
  }
  #col4{
    min-width:200px;
    width:15%;
  }
  #col5{
    min-width:200px;
    width:25%;
  }
  #row1{
    /*max-height:400px;*/
    height:200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*
    height:50%;
    */
  }
  #row2{
    height:300px;
    /*
    max-height:20px;
    height:5%;
    */
  }
  #row3{
    height:300px;
    /*
    max-height:200px;
    min-height:400px;
    */
    /*
    height:45%;
    */
  }
  #left_box{
  }
  #query_div{
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
    height: 1em; /* I don't know if you want whis */
  }
  #box1_div{
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
    height: 1em;
  }
  .hidden{
    height:0px;
    /*visibility:hidden;*/
  }
</style>  
</head>
<body onload="FillData()">
<table id="global_table" border="2">
  <!--
  <colgroup>
  <col id="col1"/>
  <col id="col2"/>
  <col id="col3"/>
  <col id="col4"/>
  <col id="col5"/>
  </colgroup>
  -->
  <tr class="hidden">
    <td id="col1" class="hidden">
    <td id="col2" class="hidden">
    <td id="col3" class="hidden">
    <td id="col4" class="hidden">
    <td id="col5" class="hidden">
  </tr>

  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="left_box" rowspan="3"><div id="query_div">Test</div></td>
    <td><div id="box1_div">Box 1</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box2_div">Box 2</div></td>
    <td><div id="box3_div">Box 3</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"><div id="box4_div">Box 4</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box4_div">Box 5</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box6_div">Box 6</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you are looking for, see [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/UqT4J/2/).

Question 1)

```
#query_div{
    overflow: hidden;
    word-break: break-all;
    height: 1em; /* I don't know if you want whis */
}
```

Question 2)

```
#row2{
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! For #2 if I were to just write 20px, what percents should I use for #row1 and #row2?

Comment: After making your changes, it seems like the minimum heights are not being respected any more....what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

I doubt this addresses all your requirements, but hopefully will get you on the right track

Play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/9965G/

or and the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function randomString(string_length) {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    return randomstring;
  }
  function FillData(){
    document.getElementById("query_div").innerHTML = randomString(1000);
  }
</script>

<style type="text/css">
  #global_table{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    max-height:1500px;
  }
  #col1{
  }
  #col2{
    min-width:200px;
    width:20%;
  }
  #col3{
    min-width:200px;
    width:25%;
  }
  #col4{
    min-width:200px;
    width:15%;
  }
  #col5{
    min-width:200px;
    width:25%;
  }
  #row1{
    height:30px;
  }
  #row2{
    height:20px;
  }
  #row3{
    /*min-height:200px;
    height:45%;*/
  }
  #left_box{
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 15%;
  }
  #query_div{
    overflow:hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
  td {
    min-width: 200px;
  }
</style>  
</head>
<body onload="FillData()">
<table id="global_table" border="2">
  <colgroup>
    <col id="col1"/>
    <col id="col2"/>
    <col id="col3"/>
    <col id="col4"/>
    <col id="col5"/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr id="row1">
    <td id="left_box" rowspan="3"><div id="query_div">Test</div></td>
    <td><div id="box1_div">Box 1</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box2_div">Box 2</div></td>
    <td><div id="box3_div">Box 3</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2"><div id="box4_div">Box 4</div></td>
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box4_div">Box 5</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td colspan="2"><div id="box6_div">Box 6</div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:
1. I moved css props from `col1` to left_box
2. it says `max-width: 200` and `width: 15%`. However it acts as if I said `min-width: 200` so it seems. I can't explain. Verify in firebug. I imagine using percentage and pixels together may cause issues... maybe something else.
3. if you want `row2` to be fixed at 20px you just say `width: 20px;` if you want to have `row1/row2 = 60/40` that means you just need to give `raw1` `width: 30px`.
4. having height for `row3` messes height for `row1` and `row2`. I removed it.
5.  I have actually very little experience with tables... I try to avoid them. Yeah, tables are supposed to work for tabular data... but good luck with that when it's less trivial. I'd go with divs and additional js if needed over trying to optimize a table.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't being clear. For #1 - if you open the code I pasted, you'll see the first column takes up a ridiculous amount of the page and you have to scroll over a lot to see the other columns. I'm not sure why this is happening though - I set the td's width, but the <div> is not respecting that width. And for #2 if I were to just write 20px, what percents should I use for #row1 and #row2?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I found that the min-widths did not work in your solution.....I found a way to make it work, but not for min-height....see above.